# How to Get Xcode to Not Automatically Open Previously Opened Projects

Tags: xcode

So, I opened a xib file from an older project and it caused a crash.  That's not the issue.  The issue is that now when I restart Xcode, it tries to open all previously opened projects (and files) and the crash re-occurs.  Where does Xcode store the list of previously open files, and how can I get it to start 'clean' without any open projects?

Update: As a note - this is the latest version of Xcode 4.2 on Lion.

Comment: As an addition to the answers, if you want to reset project state, you should remove directories: _YourProjectName.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata and YourProjectName.xcodeproj/xcuserdata_

Comment: @Borzh your comment really helped me. Thanks

Comment: a comment for my future self, deleting the project and restoring it from the trash can worked for me

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> when clicking on the Xcode icon in the dock. Xcode then starts without opening previously used projects. This is related to version Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a) but I am almost sure that I used it in older versions as well.

Comment: side note... don't do that in the Applications folder as it will highlight all the way from where you had selected (probably A...) and open all of them.  Every application in my applications folder is now launching

Comment: To reiterate, I had to pin Xcode to dock to get this to work. Launch it from Finder with this shortcut just causes it to load with slow animations.

Comment: For some reason, my XCode crashed everytime it tried to open some previously closed projects. This solution really saved my day.

Comment: That's the option I was looking for: Opening without trying to open previous project (which  was creating the issue). I could delete my account and redo it.

Comment: Did not seem to work under 15.1

Answer (score 37):

I've recently had a similar problem. I tried the methods above and could launch Xcode from the command line, but as soon as I tried to open from the finder, it would try to open the "bad" document and hang.

I eventually resolved it by removing the contents of :

```
~/Library/Autosave Information/
~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState
```

This seems to have fixed it for me.

Comment: FWIW, deleting the second directory listed alone worked for me

Answer (score 31):

I just spent half the day stressing over a very similar issue. I had tried updating and reinstalling Xcode - but the problem still persisted. Thankfully, a few minutes ago, I managed to solve this by doing what your question states with the help of [this post](http://www.codeography.com/2011/10/05/prevent-xcode-from-opening-extra-projects.html).

Basically, I opened another Xcode project (it can be any file, though) from the terminal using the following command:

```
open -a /Applications/Xcode.app app.xcodeproj/ --args -ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES
```

This successfully launched Xcode with the standard 'Welcome to Xcode' dialog box you usually get. Hope that helps!

Comment: I used simpler `open -a /Applications/Xcode5-DP2.app/ --args -ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES`

Answer (score 16):

You can stop Xcode from opening the last project by running the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ApplePersistenceIgnoreState -bool YES
```

This and other useful commands are [here](https://github.com/ctreffs/xcode-defaults).

Comment: Saved my day! Stuck on large project loading.

Comment: The true answer!

Answer (score 12):

I was able to do it with the following command line in Mavericks:

```
open -a /Applications/Xcode.app --args -ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES
```

Answer (score 10):

Not specific to Xcode:

Please make sure `Close windows when quitting an application` checkbox is checked under `System Preferences` >  `General`.

Comment: Yes this is true - but this does not address the problem in the question.  The question deals with the situation when Xcode crashes because of a problem in a file - and then will continue to try and launch that file on restart.

Comment: Yes, it does. Problem is not related to Xcode, or crashing. Re-opening last open windows is a macOS feature, and it is causing the problem OP experiencing.

Comment: It doesn't. I always had that checked but experience the same problem as op.

Comment: Wow. In 2022, this box is mysteriously checked again. Still a valid answer for the opposite solution.

Comment: This doesn't help when you can't complete the close due to hang or crash that happens before it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for the file that contains Xcode's settings, take a look at the settings themselves using the `defaults` command:

```
% defaults read com.apple.xcode | more
```

I notice two keys that might be relevant: `NSRecentXCFileDocuments` and `NSRecentXCProjectDocuments`. Both appear to be arrays, so you could reset one like this:

```
% defaults write com.apple.xcode NSRecentXCFileDocuments -array ""
```

Alternately, you could use the `defaults read` command to dump the settings into a text file, edit that, and then use `defaults write` to update the settings:

```
% defaults read com.apple.xcode > xcsettings.plist
// edit xcsettins.plist with your favorite editor
% defaults write com.apple.xcode < xcsettings.plist
```

Comment: I dropped both of those settings values as well as another setting which contained references to the open files and the projects and files are still opening on launch.

Comment: @dtuckernet A simpler approach, then: move or delete the file that's causing a problem on launch. If I understand you correctly, the issue is just that Xcode tries to open the file every time it launches, and that causes a crash? Moving the file should end that cycle.

Comment: This is old information and no longer applies to modern Xcode.

Comment: @Barry It's an old question. If you read questions that are 2 or more years old you're going to find a lot of information that's out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Given the project name "MyProject" in directory ~/Documents/Projects/MyProject do the following:

1. `cd ~/Documents/Projects`
2. `mv MyProject MyProject.x`
3. `open -a Xcode`
4. close MyProject (Option+Command+W)
5. `mv MyProject.x MyProject`
6. `open -a Xcode`

The this solved the crash for me... however my Storboard was corrupt. Fortunately the Time Machine backup of the folder was intact, I just restored it.

Answer (score 1):

For me it wasn't a project that was causing the crash on startup, it was a particular file (an sks to be exact), so Kay's answer didn't work.  When I went to open my particular project, it would still crash.

I simply temporarily deleted the file. Then I opened the project, cleaned, and re-added the file, and all was well.