# Xcode freezes/ hangs on startup and does not load any application

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently updated my M1 mac to Monterey 12.5.1 and since my xcode fail to load my project. Xcode opens and hangs as seen in the picture. I have to force quit to close.
The installed version of xcode is Version 13.4.1

Things I have tired:

1. Completely removing and reinstalling xcode from the dev site
2. Restarting device
3. Suggestion from here
   [Xcode freezes on startup while loading project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247008/xcode-freezes-on-startup-while-loading-project)
4. Even if I fully create a new project from the start screen, it still freezes on load

Nothing seems to be working. Wondering if anyone can help

Thanks [image: Example]

Comment: Step one: do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053418/how-to-get-xcode-to-not-automatically-open-previously-opened-projects to get Xcode to stop opening your project at launch.

Comment: @matt I have tried this an still the same issue. Even if i fully create a new project from the start screen, it still freezes on load

Comment: Say that in the question please.

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone who has this issue in the future. I has taken me 2 days to figure out. My code was stored on the cloud and when I moved it locally everything started working again without issues.
So the fix is not to use icloud like I did

Comment: "My code was stored on the cloud" But that was not in the question so answering it was impossible.

Comment: Certain individuals in this forum are unfortunately disrespectful and fail to comprehend the realities of others. Their self-proclaimed status falsely inflates their sense of superiority over everyone else. This particular user provided a response that could resonate with many of us, including me. It would be beneficial if we all refrained from unconstructive criticism and negativity.